# Should the editor's name be included in a rebuttal letter?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

To make things simple, I am asking whether the rebuttal letter is starting with

> Dear Editor and Reviewers

or

> Dear Reviewers

Answer (score 3):

One thing to do is to write two documents:

- a short letter to the Editor, summarizing your rebuttal in a few sentences;
- a detailed Answer to Reviewers, including line-by-line response to all comments and suggestions of the Referees.

Note that the Editor not necessarily has enough time to read through all the detailed response him/her-self, but the presence of this document re-assures that the discussion between Authors and Referees is going in the right direction. If you experience problems addressing Referees' questions, or disagree with them significantly, you should mention this in the letter to the Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you address all letters to the editor (she/he is the contact person!) and if any part of your letter is relevant to a review, than you address them, too. In practice generally t means that in the main header I address on the editor, and when I answer the reviewers, I address them there.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional review process is a communication between the editor, who have solicited reviewers to obtain critical peer review of the manuscript, and the author. As such you should respond to the editor and provide a response to the review comments by the reviewers. It is not likely the reviewers will see your response unless they agreed to re-review your revised version of the manuscript.

Open review processes are gaining ground where the entire review process is open to the public. The Open Access publisher Copernicus has such a system where anyone can leave comments to the authors. The handling editor will also appoint official reviewers who's reviews will be posted publicly. In such a system the response to the reviewers (official reviewers as well as other who have left comments will also be posted publicly. In such a case the letter can be directed both to the editor and the reviewers since at least part of the review process has the form of a public discussion (Copernicus also calls their manuscript "Discussions".

So in the traditional sense all communications will be with the editor but in the case of public discussion format review processes, the letter can be directed also to reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually address the editor since I don't ever communicate with the reviewers. However, I thank them for the report in the first sentence of the letter. I think that this corresponds well to the way how reports are written, because they are impersonal as well (they don't begin with *Dear authors*).

However, In my opinion, while one should keep a good level of politeness, your paper won't be treated any better or worse if you write *Dear Editor and Reviewers* or just *Dear Editor*.